# How to show different pages based on keyword search in Google?

Tags: seo, google, google-search, keywords, search-results

Whenever I search with any keyword of my website it showing only the homepage result, why not it showing the related page for that keyword.

For example: if I search with keyword *Properties For Rent* it's displaying only my homepage (`www.example.com`) instead of related page (`www.example.com/rent`), but some of the website showing the related page for that keyword.

Please suggest me how do I achieve this in Google SERPs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In most cases, the homepage has more SEO weight because it gets more backlinks to it than other pages.
If you want to see showing up on Google Search each page of your site for specific keywords, you can try:

- to optimize each page for these specific keywords (`<title>`, `<h1>`, etc.)
- to get more backlinks to these internal pages

Comment: @Bala These pages can also eventually show up as sitelinks. They would then be in the results page, right below the homepage.